# Возможен ли выбор между последовательной версией алгоритма и CUDA на этапе выполнения?

Tags: runtime, cuda, c++

Я реализовал две версии библиотеки: обычную с циклами и распараллеленную на CUDA. Есть ли способ собрать их в одну, которая определяла бы оборудование и если CUDA на конкретном железе не поддерживается, считало бы все в циклах? Причем делать это нужно на этапе выполнения приложения, а не компиляции.

В идеале хорошо было бы еще сначала опеределить будет ли выигрыш от CUDA или вред и затем только выбирать вариант. Возможно такое?

Comment: - Наверняка есть `API,` который позволяет получить `id` видеокарточек, используемых на машине. А дальше я бы в вашем приложении добавил бы множество `id` видеокарт, на которых запуск в `CUDA` режиме имеет смысл.

- Соответственно, в момент запуска вы спрашиваете текущую конфигурацию, и, если она допустима, то грузите библиотеку `CUDA,` если она не поддерживается - то совершаете `fallback` к обычной версии библиотеки.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо определиться, какую работу по большей части выполняет ваше ПО: вычисления или распараллеливание, т.е. насколько в вашем ПО важен интерконнект между узлами вычислителей.

Если интерконнект не сильно важен, например: испольлзуется только при загрузке задачи и выгрузке результата, то распараллеливание принесет только пользу.

Библиотеку CUDA'ы можно подключать динамически, так что автоматическое определение ее наличия сводится к наличию этой библиотеки и вызову соответствующей функции в ее API ( сейчас не помню какая именно, смотрите документацию ).

Расчитать выигрыш конечно сложнее, но можно. Он упирается в характеристики железа. В данном случае - характеристики пропускной способности транспорта обеспечивающего связь карты с компьютером - это скорость используемого PCIe и характеристики самой карты ( число вычислителей, их частота и объем ОЗУ )

Если интерконнект не важен, то считайте характеристики карты, а если важен - добавляйте к этому еще и расчет характеристик PCIe.

Comment: Так как же делать выбор?

Comment: А Вы ответили на первый вопрос?

Comment: 1. Введите эмпирический коэффициент для оценки самой библиотеки - вычисления/распараллеливание (K)
2. Введите коэффициент транспорта - время работы библиотеки на передачу данных / время работы библиотеки (Transfer)
3. Определите число параллельных ядер (Cores)

И выведите какую-нибудь простенькую формулу: Y = Transfer * K * Cores

при Y > 1 есть смысл параллелить

Comment: Ну, и уж если совсем скурпулезно к этому подходить, то Cores следует еще и домножать на частоты вычислителей ( GPU и CPU, соответственно )

Comment: Интеркоммуникации не важны.

Comment: >Интеркоммуникации не важны.
Значит K = 1.0